# Updating Multiple Tables using FORALL option in ORACLE

Tags: oracle, for-loop, plsql, oracle11g, database-performance

Could any one help me how to give multiple DML statements inside FORALL option in oracle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> how to give multiple DML statements inside FORALL

You cannot. One **FORALL** statement can support only one **DML** statement. For "n" DMLs, you need to write "n" FORALL statements.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you could put your DMLs in a single anonymous pl/sql block and run it via an execute immediate statement, as shown here (https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:9530395800346231332):

```
 forall 1 .. l_var.count
     execute immediate 'begin
     delete tab1 where id=:1;
     delete tab2 where id=:1;
     delete tab3 where id=:1;
   end;' using l_var(i);
```